# Why won't ball show up? \ball is undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer, itemize

```
%A.DOCUMENTCLASSes.
%The document class produces a style for the document. %Most papers work fine with the next one.
%For letter style see the letter document on the website.
% For presentations, see a beamer document on the website. %
%\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\documentclass{beamer} 
%\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
%B.PACKAGES to ADD
%The next commands are for latex packages which we sometimes use. %
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{paralist}
%COMMENT: The next 2 software packages are only for presentations. %
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%C. PAGE LAYOUT.
%The following commands are not for presentations!
%These commands are for creating margins, text width, text length %and double spacing for papers.
%
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{10pt} %\setlength{\textwidth}{430pt}
%\textwidth 15cm
%\oddsidemargin .2cm \evensidemargin .2cm
%\textheight 20cm
%\topmargin -.3cm
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
%D.COLORS.
%These commands are for colors for papers and presentations. %Note that \rrr makes RED, %\bbb makes BLUE,
%\ppp makes PURPLE and \ggg makes GREEN. 
\definecolor{b}{rgb}{.1,.1,.7}
\definecolor{rr}{rgb}{.8,0,.3}
\definecolor{g}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{pp}{rgb}{.5,0,.7}
\definecolor{r}{rgb}{.6,0,.3} \definecolor{y}{rgb}{.9,.99,.9} \newcommand{\rrr}{\textcolor{rr}} \newcommand{\bbb}{\textcolor{b}} \newcommand{\ppp}{\textcolor{pp}} \renewcommand{\ggg}{\textcolor{g}} \newcommand{\grr}{\ggg} \newcommand{\bbl}{\bbb}
%E.ABBREVIATIONS.
%The next commands are abbreviations used frequently % especially in multi-variable calculus.
%
\newcommand{\vr}{{\ppp{\bf r}}} \newcommand{\va}{\ppp{\bf a}} \newcommand{\vi}{{\rrr{\bf i}}} \newcommand{\vj}{{\rrr{\bf j}}} \newcommand{\vk}{{\rrr{\bf k}}} \newcommand{\vu}{\rrr{\bf u}} \newcommand{\vb}{\bbb{\bf b}} \newcommand{\vv}{\bbl{\bf v}} \newcommand{\vn}{{\ppp{\bf n}}} \newcommand{\vw}{\ppp{\bf w}} \newcommand{\rR}{\rrr{\bf R}} \newcommand{\rA}{{\rrr{\bf A}}} \newcommand{\rrth}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 3}} \newcommand{\rrtw}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 2}} \renewcommand{\v}{\overset{\longrightarrow}}
%F.NEGATIVE SPACE
%The next 3 commands are for negative spacing and are %used frequently in presentations. \newcommand{\vsp}{\vspace{-.1cm}} \newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{-.2cm}} \newcommand{\vspa}{\vspace{-.3cm}}
%G. NUMBERED THEOREMS, DEFINITIONS,...
%These commands are for papers only.
%(for presentations, they need to be commented out).
%They create numbered theorems and other numbered objects like definitions % The ``section'' part produces numbering by section.
%If you remove that part, then the section number %where the "theorem" is located will not appear
%in the numbering of the statement of the "theorem". %
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} %\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%G'.
%Some commands mostly for presentations. %
%\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} 
%\newtheorem{history}{\large History} 
%\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} 
%\newtheorem{Case}{Case} 
%\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
%H.SHORTHANDS \def and \newcommand.
%The command \def is used create abbreviations for
%frequently used symbols like the math symbol for capital R
%that we use to denote the real numbers or the Greek letter theta.
%For longer abbreviations or commands, we usually use the command %\newcommand. For example, %instead of typing \end{document}
%I usually type \ed instead.
%It may not be a good idea to use too many of
%these abbreviations if someone else (a coauthor) is
%reading your tex document, they may not understand.
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\rth{\mathbb{R}^3}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}} 
\newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}} 
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}} 
\newcommand{\ed}{\end{document}}
%X. GRAY shaded BLOCKS in presentations.
%The next 2 commands are for creating gray shaded blocks in presentations. 
\newcommand{\bblock}{\begin{block}} 
\newcommand{\eblock}{\end{block}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example (This is a very popular midterm exam problem)}
Find an \textcolor{b}{equation of the plane} which contains the points \\
$P(-1,2,1)$, $Q(1,-2,1)$, and $R(1,1,-1)$.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{Solution:}
{\bf\Large Method 1.}\\
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ball] 1
\item[\ball] 2
\item[\ball] 3
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `\begin{block}` to go with `\end{block}`. If you remove all the irrelevant material from your code, the error is easy to find.

Comment: Suggested reading: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Remove the line `\end{block}`. Also, take into account that `\bfseries` (never use `\bf` in LaTeX documents) and `\Large` are font switches and not commands with arguments, so you have to use `{\bfseries\Large text}` and not `\bfseries\Large{text}`.

Comment: I need a block in there, I got it to run but for some reason the items are not showing up and the bold and large are running through the items. I also keep getting method 1 on the top left corner

Comment: @steph You already have an `exampleblock`.

Comment: I know I am supposed to have an example block above one for a solution, my solution block Is supposed to say method 1. in bold large and underneath 3 bullets. I have this now but using \item is not showing the defined ball idk why

Comment: I added the \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball] but it isn't showing anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You had `\end{block}` without `\begin{block}{}`. Notice the pair of braces after `\begin{block}`; those are used for an eventual title for the block; if empty, no title is added.
2. Don't load the `enumitem` package with `beamer`. The `beamer` class has its own way to handle lists and `enumitem` will interfere with the `beamer` settings producing undesired results like the one you experienced.
3. Take into account that `\bfseries` (never use `\bf` in LaTeX documents) and `\Large` are font switches and not commands with arguments, so you have to use `{\bfseries\Large text}` and not `\bfseries\Large{text}`.
4. You are loading some packages that beamer already loads internally: `amsmath`, `amsthm`, `graphicx`, `color`. You can suppress the lines loading them form your code.

The code:

```
%A.DOCUMENTCLASSes.
%The document class produces a style for the document. %Most papers work fine with the next one.
%For letter style see the letter document on the website.
% For presentations, see a beamer document on the website. %
%\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\documentclass{beamer} 
%\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
%B.PACKAGES to ADD
%The next commands are for latex packages which we sometimes use. %
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
%COMMENT: The next 2 software packages are only for presentations. %
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%C. PAGE LAYOUT.
%The following commands are not for presentations!
%These commands are for creating margins, text width, text length %and double spacing for papers.
%
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{10pt} %\setlength{\textwidth}{430pt}
%\textwidth 15cm
%\oddsidemargin .2cm \evensidemargin .2cm
%\textheight 20cm
%\topmargin -.3cm
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
%D.COLORS.
%These commands are for colors for papers and presentations. %Note that \rrr makes RED, %\bbb makes BLUE,
%\ppp makes PURPLE and \ggg makes GREEN. 
\definecolor{b}{rgb}{.1,.1,.7}
\definecolor{rr}{rgb}{.8,0,.3}
\definecolor{g}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{pp}{rgb}{.5,0,.7}
\definecolor{r}{rgb}{.6,0,.3} \definecolor{y}{rgb}{.9,.99,.9} \newcommand{\rrr}{\textcolor{rr}} \newcommand{\bbb}{\textcolor{b}} \newcommand{\ppp}{\textcolor{pp}} \renewcommand{\ggg}{\textcolor{g}} \newcommand{\grr}{\ggg} \newcommand{\bbl}{\bbb}
%E.ABBREVIATIONS.
%The next commands are abbreviations used frequently % especially in multi-variable calculus.
%
\newcommand{\vr}{{\ppp{\bf r}}} \newcommand{\va}{\ppp{\bf a}} \newcommand{\vi}{{\rrr{\bf i}}} \newcommand{\vj}{{\rrr{\bf j}}} \newcommand{\vk}{{\rrr{\bf k}}} \newcommand{\vu}{\rrr{\bf u}} \newcommand{\vb}{\bbb{\bf b}} \newcommand{\vv}{\bbl{\bf v}} \newcommand{\vn}{{\ppp{\bf n}}} \newcommand{\vw}{\ppp{\bf w}} \newcommand{\rR}{\rrr{\bf R}} \newcommand{\rA}{{\rrr{\bf A}}} \newcommand{\rrth}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 3}} \newcommand{\rrtw}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 2}} \renewcommand{\v}{\overset{\longrightarrow}}
%F.NEGATIVE SPACE
%The next 3 commands are for negative spacing and are %used frequently in presentations. \newcommand{\vsp}{\vspace{-.1cm}} \newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{-.2cm}} \newcommand{\vspa}{\vspace{-.3cm}}
%G. NUMBERED THEOREMS, DEFINITIONS,...
%These commands are for papers only.
%(for presentations, they need to be commented out).
%They create numbered theorems and other numbered objects like definitions % The ``section'' part produces numbering by section.
%If you remove that part, then the section number %where the "theorem" is located will not appear
%in the numbering of the statement of the "theorem". %
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} %\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%G'.
%Some commands mostly for presentations. %
%\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} 
%\newtheorem{history}{\large History} 
%\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} 
%\newtheorem{Case}{Case} 
%\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
%H.SHORTHANDS \def and \newcommand.
%The command \def is used create abbreviations for
%frequently used symbols like the math symbol for capital R
%that we use to denote the real numbers or the Greek letter theta.
%For longer abbreviations or commands, we usually use the command %\newcommand. For example, %instead of typing \end{document}
%I usually type \ed instead.
%It may not be a good idea to use too many of
%these abbreviations if someone else (a coauthor) is
%reading your tex document, they may not understand.
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\rth{\mathbb{R}^3}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}} 
\newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}} 
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}} 
\newcommand{\ed}{\end{document}}
%X. GRAY shaded BLOCKS in presentations.
%The next 2 commands are for creating gray shaded blocks in presentations. 
\newcommand{\bblock}{\begin{block}} 
\newcommand{\eblock}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example (This is a very popular midterm exam problem)}
Find an \textcolor{b}{equation of the plane} which contains the points \\
$P(-1,2,1)$, $Q(1,-2,1)$, and $R(1,1,-1)$.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{Solution:}
{\bfseries\Large Method 1.}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want the format of the blocks to be like this I want it to be the way I have it. I just want ball to show up:\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example (This is a very popular midterm exam problem)}
Find an \textcolor{b}{equation of the plane} which contains the points \\
$P(-1,2,1)$, $Q(1,-2,1)$, and $R(1,1,-1)$.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{Solution:}
{\bf\Large Method 1.}\\
\begin{itemize}
\item[] 1
\item[\ball] 2
\item[\ball] 3
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: @steph Please see my updated answer. I gave you two options for the block and also solved the problem with the itemize.